# delete Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, python-2.x

I try to delete the node of Binary Search Tree
The outcome I've gotten when I print out is actually None
This deletion, actually can delete anything key from the binary tree itself.

I'm new to Binary Search Tree.
Can someone help me out with my code?
You help will be apprieciated.

Thanks

```
def deleteMin(self):
    self.root = self.deleteMin2(self.root)

def deleteMin2(self, node):
    if node.left is None:
        return node.right
    node.left = self.deleteMin2(node.left)
    node.count = 1 + self.size2(node.left) + self.size2(node.right)
    return node

def delete(self,key):
    self.root = self.delete2(self.root,key)

def delete2(self,node,key):
    if node is None:
        return None
    if key < node.key:
        node.left = self.delete2(node.left,key)
    elif(key > node.key):
        node.right = self.delete2(node.right,key)
    else:
        if node.right is None:
            return node.left
        if node.left is None:
            return node.right
        t = node
        node = self.min(t.right)
        node.right = self.deleteMin2(t.right)
        node.left = t.left
    node.count = self.size2(node.left) + self.size2(node.right) + 1
    return node
```

Full Code

```
import os
import pygraphviz as pgv
from collections import deque


class BST:
    root=None

    def put(self, key, val):
        self.root = self.put2(self.root, key, val)

    def put2(self, node, key, val):
        if node is None:
            #key is not in tree, create node and return node to parent
            return Node(key, val)
        if key < node.key:
            # key is in left subtree
            node.left = self.put2(node.left, key, val)
        elif key > node.key:
            # key is in right subtree
            node.right = self.put2(node.right, key, val)
        else:
            node.val = val
        node.count = 1 + self.size2(node.left) + self.size2(node.right)
        return node




    # draw the graph
    def drawTree(self, filename):
        # create an empty undirected graph
        G=pgv.AGraph('graph myGraph {}')

        # create queue for breadth first search
        q = deque([self.root])
        # breadth first search traversal of the tree
        while len(q) <> 0:
            node = q.popleft()
            G.add_node(node, label=node.key+":"+str(node.val))
            if node.left is not None:
                # draw the left node and edge
                G.add_node(node.left, label=node.left.key+":"+str(node.left.val))
                G.add_edge(node, node.left)
                q.append(node.left)
            if node.right is not None:
                # draw the right node and edge
                G.add_node(node.right, label=node.right.key+":"+str(node.right.val))
                G.add_edge(node, node.right)
                q.append(node.right)

        # render graph into PNG file
        G.draw(filename,prog='dot')
        os.startfile(filename)

    def createTree(self):
        #root
        self.put("F",6)
        self.put("D",4)
        self.put("C",3)
        self.put("B",2)
        self.put("A",1)
        self.put("E",5)
        self.put("I",9)
        self.put("G",7)
        self.put("H",8)
        self.put("J",10)

   def get(self,key):
        temp = self.root
        while temp is not None:
            #if what you are searching for is the root
            if temp.key == key:
                return temp.val
            #if it's not the root
            #check to see if what you're searching for is less than the root key
            #if so, search left
            elif temp.key > key:
                temp = temp.left
            #else search right
            else:
                temp = temp.right
        return None



    def size(self,key):
        node = self.root
        #if root is not none
        while node is not None:
        #if the given node is the current node
            if node.key == key:
                #return itself
                return self.size2(node)
        #if the node that you are at is smaller than root
            elif node.key > key:
                node = node.left
            else:
                node = node.right

    def size2(self,n):
        #if node is none
        if n is None:
            #return 0
            return 0
        else:
            #else track
            return n.count

    def depth(self, key):
        return self.depth2(self.root, key)

    def depth2(self, root, key, current_depth=0):
        #if given node is not in the tree
        if not root:
            return -1
        #inspect given key against current node (root)
        #if current node and given node is match
        elif root.key == key:
            return current_depth
        #if given node is less than current node
        elif key < root.key:
            return self.depth2(root.left, key, current_depth + 1)
        else:
            return self.depth2(root.right, key, current_depth + 1)


    def height(self,key):
        node = self.root
        #if root is not none
        while node is not None:
        #if what you are searching for is the root
            if node.key == key:
                #return itself
                return self.height2(node)
        #if the node that you are at is smaller than root
            elif node.key > key:
                node = node.left
            else:
                node = node.right


    def height2(self,n):
        if n is None:
            return -1
        else:
            #return the max
            return  1 + max(self.height2(n.left),self.height2(n.right))


    def inOrder(self,n):
        if n is None:
            return 0
        else:
            self.inOrder(n.left)
            print n.key , ": " , n.val;
            self.inOrder(n.right)

    def preOrder(self,n):
        if n is None:
            return 0
        else:
            print n.key , ": " , n.val;
            self.preOrder(n.left)
            self.preOrder(n.right)

    def postOrder(self,n):
        if n is None:
            return 0
        else:
            self.postOrder(n.left)
            self.postOrder(n.right)
            print n.key , ": " , n.val;

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def deleteMin(self):
        self.root = self.deleteMin2(self.root)

    def deleteMin2(self, node):
        if node.left is None:
            return node.right
        node.left = self.deleteMin2(node.left)
        node.count = 1 + self.size2(node.left) + self.size2(node.right)
        return node

    def delete(self,key):
        self.root = self.delete2(self.root,key)

    def delete2(self,node,key):
        if node is None:
            return None
        if key < node.key:
            node.left = self.delete2(node.left,key)
        elif(key > node.key):
            node.right = self.delete2(node.right,key)
        else:
            if node.right is None:
                return node.left
            if node.left is None:
                return node.right
            t = node
            node = self.min(t.right)
            node.right = self.deleteMin2(t.right)
            node.left = t.left
        node.count = self.size2(node.left) + self.size2(node.right) + 1
        return node


class Node:
    left = None
    right = None
    key = 0
    val = 0
    count = 0



    def __init__(self, key, val):
        self.key = key
        self.val = val
        self.count += 1




bst = BST()
bst.createTree()
bst.drawTree("demo.png")
node = bst.root
print "Get: " , bst.get("C") , "\n"
print "Size: ", bst.size("D"), "\n"
print "Depth:", bst.depth("B"), "\n"
print "Height:", bst.height("B"), "\n"
print "\n In Order"
bst.inOrder(node)
print "\n Pre Order \n"
bst.preOrder(node)
print "\n Post Order \n"
bst.postOrder(node)


node = bst.root
print  bst.delete(node)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code you give lacks the method `min`. That method finds the minimum node in the subtree rooted at the node being deleted:

```
def min(self, node):
    if node.left is None:
        return node
    else:
        return self.min(node.left)
```

The `delete` method does not return anything, that is why `bst.delete(node)` prints None. By the way, delete method expects a key, not the node itself. After you add the above `min` method to BST class, try changing the last two lines to something like:

```
print "root: " + bst.root.key
bst.delete(bst.root.key)
print "root: " + bst.root.key
```

And you will see it prints first "F" and then we delete "F" which happens to be the root. After that root becomes "G" and it is printed.

To delete any arbitrary node, just do `bst.delete(key)` where key is the key of the node you want to delete.

Comment: Hi, what if I wanted to delete any node?

Comment: Please check the last paragraph, you just call delete method with the key of the node you want deleted. I have edited the answer to change the call to delete method, my mistake.

Comment: I've run the code, but it actually didn't remove altho it printed out the node is G now. but in my binary search tree image, F is still there.

Comment: @stack are you sure? Because when i delete F and then print the traversals, F is really gone and G becomes the new root. Make sure you draw the tree after deleting F.

Comment: I just use your code exactly and tho it print out the root is "g" but the tree still printed "F"

Answer (score -1):

You can delete attributes with `del` but that I'm not sure if that's what you want to do:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = 1
n = Node()
n
<__main__.Node object at 0x101e6f278>
n.root
1
del(n.root)
n
<__main__.Node object at 0x101e6f278>
n.root
Traceback (most recent call last):
    Python Shell, prompt 6, line 1
builtins.AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'root'
```

Comment: What do I mean about what?  You can delete the nodes with del as shown.  What isn't clear to you?